# Size of 64-bit dll 50% larger than 32-bit

Tags: c++, 64-bit, visual-c++

I have a VC++ project (2005) that generates both 32-bit and 64-bit dlls. The 32-bit dll is 1044 KB whereas the 64-bit version is 1620 KB. I'm curious why the size is so large. Is it just because of the larger address size, or is there a compiler option that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you statically linking in the runtime? Then it is most certainly the runtime that is adding _most_ of the overhead.

Comment: There is not enough infomration to provide a meaningful answer. Anything provided will be pure speculation.

Comment: Anecdotally, x64 code size does increase by 50% to 66% over equivalent x86 code.  I assumed that the increase was mainly due to size of pointers (including function call target addresses).  However, I haven't seen any kind of rigorous study/analysis; I think that would definitely be interesting - I hope someone posts a pointer.

Comment: I'm not statically linking anything other than the zlib library, but that's in both versions of the dll. Incidentally the 64-bit zlib library is also ~50% larger than the 32-bit (147KB vs 101KB)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe your code contains a lot of pointers.

> [**The Free Lunch Is Over**](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/concurrency-ddj.htm)
>
> ....
>
> (Aside:
> Here’s an anecdote to demonstrate
> “space is speed” that recently hit my
> compiler team. The compiler uses the
> same source base for the 32-bit and
> 64-bit compilers; the code is just
> compiled as either a 32-bit process or
> a 64-bit one. The 64-bit compiler
> gained a great deal of baseline
> performance by running on a 64-bit
> CPU, principally because the 64-bit
> CPU had many more registers to work
> with and had other code performance
> features. All well and good. But what
> about data? **Going to 64 bits didn’t**
> **change the size of most of the data in**
> **memory, except that of course pointers**
> **in particular were now twice the size**
> **they were before. As it happens, our**
> **compiler uses pointers much more**
> **heavily in its internal data**
> **structures than most other kinds of**
> **applications ever would.** Because
> pointers were now 8 bytes instead of 4
> bytes, a pure data size increase, we
> saw a significant increase in the
> 64-bit compiler’s working set. That
> bigger working set caused a
> performance penalty that almost
> exactly offset the code execution
> performance increase we’d gained from
> going to the faster processor with
> more registers. As of this writing,
> the 64-bit compiler runs at the same
> speed as the 32-bit compiler, even
> though the source base is the same for
> both and the 64-bit processor offers
> better raw processing throughput.
> Space is speed.)

Comment: Note that this snippet is talking about the size of data, not the sie of code.  But I think the results and reasons will be similar for code and data.

Answer (score 3):

x86-64 has more registers. As a result, opcodes need more bits to specify them. Also, per x86 tradition you can specify parts of a register, and you now have a 32 bit partial register. Instructions that don't use registers are rare, so these change affects almost every instruction. Since x86-64 is still a CISC variable-length ISA, it doesn't mean that each instructions grew from 32 to 64 bits, but there is a definite growth.

Another change is that `movq`, the opcode to set a register to a constant requires 64 bit constants (but other constants in opcodes still are 32 bits)

Comment: Additionally, every instruction that accesses one of the extended registers (r8-r15 or xmm8-xmm15) needs to use the REX prefix, which adds an additional 4 bits to the size of each instruction. It does not matter if they are 64-bit operations or not; for instance addl %eax, %ebx will by 4 bits shorter than addl %eax, %r8d. (Compilers should take this into account and use registers giving the shorter code size where possible, but I don't know specifically if Visual C does so).

Answer (score 2):

Your pointer size has doubled, so if you have lots of pointers in your code, your executable can grow easily by 50%.